# Collision depending of side of the rectangle?

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

Im not intrested in the code for this problem i just want to be pointed in the right direction.

Im using C# XNA if that helps.

Basicaly for my game i am adding collisions for example the player can't walk or fall through stones.. I have the rectangle and i know i use the .intersects comand but would i need to check collision depending on the side of the rectangle here?

I know if the player is falling i can make if playerRectangle intersects stoneRectangle playerY = stopFalling..

But if the rectangle is coliding on the side of the player.. That would be different wouldn't it ?

Comment: As Duckett pointed out, checking Gamedev would give plenty of results. My own answer to a similar question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15942/2d-platformer-collision-physics-problems/15968#15968

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way of dealing with this is to work out the main axis of penetration, i.e. is the player further into the rectangle horizontally, or vertically. Then, using this information, you'd move the player so they were just touching the rectangle.

i.e. Player bumps into a wall on his right.

Main axis is Horizontal, and he's to the left of the centre of the rectangle, so we know to move him left.

---

Searching on [gamedev.stackexchange.com](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com) will give you lots of different collision detection/response options.

Answer (score 3):

If your game is 2D I would recommend using something like [FarSeer Physics](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/) rather than implementing yourself.

If you are interested in the algorithms it is open source and you can poke around the code to see how they implemented collision detection.

Comment: For very simple 2D games Farseer can be a bit too much. I'd still recommend it if the game does not involve discrete movement (i.e. no Flashback or Prince of Persia descendant). And always create a quick prototype to check if Farseer adds too much complexity.